# Using while loops to validate input

Tags: java, validation, input

I want to make the user enter only "y" "Y" "n" or "N". The resulting code asks the user to enter Y or N when they have entered the correct input, the opposite of what I expected by placing the ! in front of input.equalscaseignore(input).

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class inputVal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Input;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter Y or N. ");
        Input = keyboard.nextLine();

        while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter Y or N");
            Input = keyboard.nextLine();

        }


        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem is if user input N then !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") become true ..and if user input Y then !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N") become true so it always go to inside of the while

Answer (score 6):

It is your `or` condition, you must change it to `and`

```
while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

Just reading it out loud would help understand the logic:

WHILE Input doesn't equal (ignore case) "Y" **AND** Input doesn't equal (ignore case) "N"

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @gtgaxiola's answer:

```
!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")
```

Suppose `Input` is `"Y"`.  The left operand of `||` is `false`, since `Input` equals `"Y"`.  But the right operand is `true`, since `Input` is not equal to `"N"`.  And `false || true` is `true`, since the result of `||` is `true` whenever either operand is `true`.  In fact, this expression is always going to be `true` no matter what `Input` is.

That's why you need to use `&&`:

```
!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")
```

because you want the result to be `true` only if **both** `equalsIgnoreCase` calls return `false`.

Alternatively, you could say

```
! (Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

See also this article on [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

(By the way, the convention in Java is to use names starting with lower-case letters for variables, i.e. `input`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean logic is what's killing you here

```
while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

You want to be in the loop while the input is not Y AND not N, therefore you need to change it to

```
while (!Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !Input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

Answer (score 0):

My code logic is rusty but I believe that the issue is in the || operand.

One of the answers will always be FALSE therefor it won't enter the loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is great tool to trace your code with:
http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#